# how to access the html element dom using angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-select2

For developers who used to the `JQuery` for many years, we used to get the html element always.
I find it very tricky in `angularjs`, 
I'm looking for an equivalent of `$(selector)`.
I'll give you an example where I need the HTML element.
I'm using `select2` as my dropdown when i need to set the defualt value I need to run the following code:

```
$("#id").select2('data', { id: id, text: text });
```

because `select2` `angularjs` wrapper is not binding properly.

Or if anyone can help with maybe a different way of thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operating with HTML elements directly with Angular is not an optimal way and is bound to cause issues.

If you are using `select2` with Angular you might want to take a look at the following NPM package that works as a wrapper for `select2` with Angular.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-select2

Comment: select2 was just an example and why i don't wat to go with the angularjs library because i have done huge modifications on select2 to work the best with my projects so i'll need a huge efforts to redo it again.